# Use JNI enabled Lib in java class

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have compiled a wrapper for a native DLL with usage of JNI.
Now I want to use this library in my app but I have no idea how to access the function of this library.

I use:

```
public class JNIViie {

    private JFrame frame;
    
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("MySDK");
    }
    
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String mkey = "1234";
        
        String out = stringFromJNI(mkey);
        
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                
                try {
                    JNIViie window = new JNIViie();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public JNIViie() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    
    public native String stringFromJNI(String mkey);
    

}
```

The JNI Library I create with CMake is:
cpp file

```
//
// Created by ingo on 31.03.20.
//

#include "MySDK.h"
#include <tchar.h>

#include <jni.h>
#include <string>

MySDK::MySDK (const TCHAR * licensekey){

    int32 res = ::Initialize(licensekey, BS_ASPI_INTERNAL, BS_TRUE);
    //int32 res = ::CheckLicenseKey(licensekey);


}

std::string MySDK::driveList() {
    int32 res =  ::RescanDevices();


    std::string mydrives;

    TCHAR chListDevices[26][50];
    int32 nUsed = 0;
    res = ::GetDevices(chListDevices, &nUsed, false);

    if (BS_SDK_ERROR_NO == res) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nUsed; i++) {
            mydrives.append(chListDevices[i]);
            mydrives.append(" | ");
        }
    }

    return mydrives;
}

MySDK::~MySDK() {

}

static MySDK *example = NULL;

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_mysdk_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject thiz,
        jstring lkey){
    const TCHAR *licenceKey = env->GetStringUTFChars(lkey, JNI_FALSE);
    //const TCHAR *licenceKey = "1234";
    example = new MySDK(licenceKey);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(lkey, licenceKey);

    std::string hello = "Hello from ingo";
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_mysdk_MainActivity_drivelist(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject thiz
        ){

    std::string drives= example->driveList();

    return env->NewStringUTF(drives.c_str());
}
```

header file

```
//
// Created by ingo on 31.03.20.
//

#ifndef MYSDK_MYSDK_H
#define MYSDK_MYSDK_H
#include <string>

class MySDK {
public:

    MySDK(const TCHAR * licensekey);
    ~MySDK();

    std::string driveList();
};


#endif //MYSDK_MYSDK_H
```

Always `stringFromJNI(mkey);` is not known. Im sure I have missed something to add, but I think I need help to know what I have missed.

My package looks like this (image):[image: Package View]

Comment: `Java_com_example_mysdk_MainActivity_stringFromJNI` means that the `native` method must be declared in a class named `MainActivity` in the package `com.example.mysdk`. You'll have to change the naming either on the C++ side or the Java side so that they match.

Comment: @Michael I have now cahnged it toJava_com_example_mysdk_ JNIViie_stringFromJNI but it looks like that the function is not detected too.

Comment: Like I said, the package name must also match. So either remove it from the C function name, or move your Java class to the correct package.

Comment: always create the JNI header file with `javac -h` and use the function names it contains; recreate it when any name changes on the Java side and change you native code accordingly